# how to see browser plug-in logs in hp webos?

Tags: webos

I have developed a plug-in with the help of "**NPAPI**" approach, and i have able to launch it in browser of "**webos**" emulator. When i launch a test html page using tomcat server that page is loading fine and able to access browser plug-in.
I have added some "**printf**" statement. I tried log command in putty to see the browser logs and it is displaying browser logs but that logs doesn't contain plug-in logs.

please give me some suggestion.

thanks

Comment: Have you verified that the plugin is actually loaded on the device by looking at the process's memory map? For webOS 3, the browser would only load plugins that had a valid crypto signature.

Answer (score 0):

Printf isn't the right way to log stuff.  I believe what you want to do is to use the `syslog()` function.   You might find something useful here:

https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/pdk_app_debugging.html

You could also open a file in /media/internal/ and write to that.

Comment: thanks for reply, but sorry to say i tried syslog() function also in the log it is not coming. this plug-in is associated with browser application and i checked browser application logs using log command in putty their also plug-in's logs are not coming.